# How to click through a Rectangle (like mouseChildren = true)

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I have this problem, I use this image pan class: http://www.lextalkington.com/blog/2009/08/auto-pan-class-for-panning-an-image-on-mouse-movement/

but the problem is that the objects/sprites/movieclips that are in it have to be clickable, only problem is that the mouseChildren adn mouseEnabled properties can't be applied to a Rectangle object.

Anyone has an idea on how to be able to click through this so I can acces my objects in the panned item? (if that makes any sense...)

Answer (score 1):

This class is using a `Rectangle` as the `scrollRect` for the image. The `scrollRect` only specifies the visible area of the image. It is not the thing you want to detect mouse clicks on.

Instead, you can listen for a mouse click on the image itself.

From the code you linked to, the image is a `DisplayObject` variable named `_clip`.

In the constructor for that image panning class, you can add your mouse listener:

```
_clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onImageClick);
```

Then define the event handler:

```
private function onImageClick(event:Event):void
{
   // do something
}
```

By the way, since `_clip` is a `DisplayObject`, it doesn't have `mouseChildren` or `mouseEnabled` properties (those are defined in subclasses of DisplayObject).

Answer (score -1):

```
_clip.mouseEnable = false;
```

this should work, considering tha _clip will be clicked through